# MATLAB Saving multiple figures to a PDF

Tags: matlab

Is there any way to do this?

I know how to use saveas (`saveas(1, filename, 'pdf');`) to save one figure to a PDF file, but is it possible to add multiples? So something like (`saveas(1,2,3) filename, 'pdf'));`.

Thanks

Comment: You *might* be able to do what you want with `hgsave`...

Comment: Actually cancel that. The `hgsave` will only work with a .fig extension. From the documentation it *looks* like it might work with other file-types, but in practice it doesn't (well, not on my machine - Linux Mint, running R2012b)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so - you need to increment the file name in some manner.  I would use something like:

```
for ii=1:3
    saveas(ii,[filename '-' num2str(ii)],'pdf)
end
```

As a side note, I have had repeated difficulties when including the pdfs generated by matlab in a manuscript submission.  My current solution is to produce eps files and convert with a shell script.

r/

Comment: Agreed (+1). Also, I thought you might be interested to know: you can save multiple figures to one file using `hgsave`. However, as near as I can tell, it only works with the .fig extension. I've added an answer with some example code pointing out how it is done.

Answer (score 3):

I thought it might be worth pointing out that the behavior you are aiming for can be obtained using `hgsave` and `hgload`, BUT only if you are happy to save using .fig. The documentation for these functions fooled me for a while into believing they could work with other extensions (such as .pdf), but I couldn't get an example to work on my machine (Linux Mint v12, Matlab r2012b). Perhaps someone else might be able to do better. An example of it working with the .fig extension follows:

```
%# Create some example data
x = (0:10)';
y1 = (1/10) * x;
y2 = sin(x);

%# Create an array of figures and an array of axes
AllFig(1) = figure('Visible', 'off');
AllFig(2) = figure('Visible', 'off');
AllAxes(1) = axes('Parent', AllFig(1));
AllAxes(2) = axes('Parent', AllFig(2));

%# Plot the data on the appropriate axes
plot(AllAxes(1), y1);
plot(AllAxes(2), y2);

%# Save both figures to .fig in one hit using hgsave
hgsave(AllFig, 'TwoFigsOneFile.fig');

% Clear the workspace
clear

%# Load both figures in one hit using hgload
LoadFig = hgload('TwoFigsOneFile.fig');

%# Display the first figure and second figure
figure(LoadFig(1));
figure(LoadFig(2));
```

Comment: I did not know about this. I found this extremely powerful.

Answer (score 3):

Late reply, but I thought I'd add that you could use the publish command and publish to pdf. Create an m-file 'myfile.m' with the plot commands, as in

```
plot(x1,y1);
plot(x2,y2);
```

Then run this file using

```
publish('myfile.m', 'pdf')
```

This should give you what you want.

Answer (score 3):

### The MATLAB-PDFLaTeX solution

Using MATLAB's `publish` command is a great solution, as other answers have pointed out. If you are looking for more control in terms of how the different figures are combined, another solution is to use `pdflatex` to compile the figures into a single PDF.

1. Print the figures to PDF
2. Generate `LaTeX` code which includes the figures
3. Compile with `PDFLaTeX`

Below is a **proof of concept** which takes a file name as a `char` and some number of `function_handle`s and produces a PDF which contains those figures.

```
function res = save2pdf(name,varargin)
pathToPdflatex = '/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex' ; 

files = cell(size(varargin)) ;
for ii = 1:numel(varargin)
    files{ii} = sprintf('%s_fig%g.pdf',name,ii) ;
    print(varargin{ii},'-dpdf','-painters',files{ii}) ;
end

fh = fopen(sprintf('%s.tex',name),'w+') ;
fprintf(fh,'\\documentclass{article}\n') ;
fprintf(fh,'\\usepackage{graphicx}\n') ;
fprintf(fh,'\\begin{document}\n') ;
for ii = 1:numel(files)
    fprintf(fh,'\\includegraphics[width=\\textwidth]{%s}\n\\newpage\n',files{ii}) ;
end
fprintf(fh,'\\end{document}\n') ;
fclose(fh) ;

[~,res] = system(sprintf('%s %s.tex',pathToPdflatex,name)) ;
disp(res)
end
```

**Example:**

```
n = 1e+5 ;
x0 = cumsum(randn(n,1)) ;
x1 = cumsum(randn(n,1)) ;
f0 = figure() ;
f1 = figure() ;
ax0 = axes('Parent',f0) ;
ax1 = axes('Parent',f1) ;
plot(ax0,x0) ;
plot(ax1,x1) ;

save2pdf('my_figures',f0,f1)
```

voila:

```
...
Output written on my_figures.pdf (2 pages, 169718 bytes).
Transcript written on my_figures.log.
```

Comment: A universally experienced shortcoming of matlab. Good solution

Comment: Another option would be to call [matlab2tikz](https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz) and create a *.tex tikz plot and incorporate it in the document. Especially useful if you want to adjust fonts, colours etc. Also, Mathworks now suggests to use [saveas](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/saving-your-work.html) as option to incorporate plots in Latex documents. Also useful if you don't want each figure on an individual page.

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuild command to save all figure in one pdf, there are many workaround tough

1. Create pdf files for each figure and combine them using software which are easily available.
2. There is script called Export_fig (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629) which can save figures in single pdf
3. Save all figures in .ps format and convert .ps into PDF (I find quite easy to use).
   fname = 'test.ps';
   print ( '-dpsc2', fname, '-f1' )
   print ( '-dpsc2', fname, '-append', '-f2' )