# Save multiple figures in one pdf

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to save/combine all the existing figures, created in a loop, in one pdf file instead having multiple pdfs. Let's say one figure per page.

```
x = rand(5,100); 
y = rand(5,100); 

for i = 1:5 
    plot(x(i,:), y(i,:)); 
    filename_string = ['Plot_Number_', num2str(i),'_' ,'pdf']; 
    print(gcf, '-dpdf', '-r600', filename_string); 
    saveas(gcf,'testx', 'pdf');
end
```

Comment: Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188572/matlab-saving-multiple-figures-to-a-pdf), bunch of options available for you.

Comment: Thanks Adam but non of them work for me, I don't know how to modify those codes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MATLAB Saving multiple figures to a PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188572/matlab-saving-multiple-figures-to-a-pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add `figure` on every plot, this will keep each plot on different
  window
- Make the `filename_string`  the plot title
- Name the code with the plot, i.e `filename.m`

---

- Make another m file, let's say `main.m`
- Use `publish(filename', options)` to get the pdf file `filename.pdf`
- Before using `publish` define the `options`

```
options.format = 'pdf'
options.showCode = false
```

> Run `main.m` and check the current directory you may see an **HTML** directory
>   where you can find the pdf file named `filename.pdf`

---

## Code is as follows

---

***filename.m***

```
close all
clear
clc
x = rand(5,100); 
y = rand(5,100); 

for i = 1:5 
    figure% keep plots on different windows
    plot(x(i,:), y(i,:)); 
    title(['Plot Number ', num2str(i)], 'color', 'red', 'fontSize', 25)
end
```

---

***main.m***

```
close all
clear
clc
options.format = 'pdf';
options.showCode = false;
publish('filename.m', options)
```

Comment: Thanks Adam but I am getting an error with publish('file_to_save.m', options);

Comment: Thank you very much Adam, but it didn't work. It starts creating repeated figures.

Comment: I don't have that, I am using online MATLAB!

Answer (score 0):

Use subplot?

```
x = rand(5,100);
y = rand(5,100); 

figure();
for i = 1:5
    subplot(1,5,i); hold on;
    plot(x(i,:), y(i,:));
    title(['Plot_Number_', num2str(i)]);
end
filename_string = ['Plots','_' ,'pdf']; 
print(gcf, '-dpdf', '-r600', filename_string); 
saveas(gcf,'testx', 'pdf');
```